# What is a Netflix Word™?

Tags: word, wordplay

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Netflix Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Netflix Words™ | Non-Netflix Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| docs | slides |
| vaccine | cure |
| hacks | aimbot |
| facsimile | copy |
| checks | cash |
| ballocks | testes |
| lacrosse | backstroke |

CSV:

```
Netflix Words™, Non-Netflix Words™
docs, slides
vaccine, cure
hacks, aimbot
facsimile, copy
checks, cash
ballocks, testes
lacrosse, backstroke
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Netflix Word™ or not on its own.

*Happy Puzzling!*

Comment: If only that bottom row were the other way around...!

Comment: Not that simple...  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Netflix words are often written informally with an X. Dox (docs), vx (vaccine), etc. This explains the title, as it utilizes the informal "flix" over the formal "flicks."

Comment: This is pretty much the correct answer, however I'd appreciate it if you could add a bit more detail to your answer and explain their name!